# Docker container for development

Tags: windows, git, filesystems, docker

I have question about docker and using it in development on windows.

I have boot2docker installed and I am able to install a container and access it with ip provided by "boot2docker ip" command. But how should i set up my project on Widnows to edit code of my app in container. for example. I have a container with lighttp and some HTML5 and JS app inside. How can I enable my host machine (Windows) to access this code?

I know i could just make git repository on my local machine and commit code to remote repo on container, but it is not very practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you're developing inside a docker container and you are trying to get your source from your container?

I guess the easiest way would be to put your source inside a shared volume with the boot2docker and then use scp protocol to get those file back.

On another hand if you're wanting to share a folder between the boot2docker vm and your windows host i suggest you read this tutorial : http://www.incrediblemolk.com/sharing-a-windows-folder-with-the-boot2docker-vm/

Hope it was helpful.